# In Android, how to detect a component (like TextView) has been drawn?

Tags: android

When the user launches an app, (I guess) the interface is shown by components, like Button, TextView, LinearLayout and so on.

The question is how to detect such a component has just been drawn (i.e. user can see it)?

For example, right after it is drawn, output a string "component_id is drawn".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ViewTreeObserver.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new OnDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDraw() {

                   Log.i("component","is drawn");

        }

    });
```

Comment: If it matters in the case, onDraw() is invoked when a view is about to be drawn, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener.html#onDraw())